# Doors, creating link from one baseline to another baseline

Tags: ibm-doors

I am using Doors 9.6.1 and DXL scripting.

Consider **Module A** and **Module B**, I would like to link objects in a baseline of **Module A** to a baseline of **Module B**.

---

I tried the following, consider this **Scenario 1**:

**Baseline 1.0 of Module B** is generated, and links are created from **actual Module A** to **Baseline 1.0 of Module B**, the outgoing links from **actual Module A** link to **Baseline 1.0 of Module B** and the outgoing links from **Baseline 1.0 of Module B** link to **actual Module A**.

I generate **Baseline 1.0 of Module A**, and the links remain the same, in the actual module I delete the objects, but then links from **Baseline 1.0 of Module B** are broken because they point to links in **actual Module A**, I was hoping that when generating **Baseline 1.0 of Module A**, the incoming links would be updated to link to the objects in **Baseline 1.0 of Module A**, rather than to the objects in **actual Module A**.

---

I also tried the following, consider this **Scenario 2**:

I generate **Baseline 1.0 of Module A** and **Baseline 1.0 of Module B** attempting to create the links afterwards, but it is not possible in Doors to create links between baselines.

---

Hopefully I managed to explain it properly, if something is not clear please let me know.

My question comes down to this, is it possible in Doors to generate a bidirectional link between **Baseline 1.0 of Module A** and **Baseline 1.0 of Module B**? And in that case, how is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not work with bidirectional links in Doors. A typical scenario is that one Module contains high level requirements (let's say "SYS" for system requirements), this module is completed and baselined. Later, a module with low level requirements (let's say "HR" for hardware requirements) is created, each requirements in HR corresponds to a requirement in SYS, the relation might be called "refines". This module will probably be baselined much later.

If you have two modules A and B and both are developed at the same time and both link to one another, you might get problems later, e.g. when you want to create a valid requirements report, a dependency or coverage report.

Having said that and if you still want to go on with your approach, I think your solution is "Baseline Sets".

- Project --> Properties --> Baseline Set Definitions
- Create a new Baseline Set Definition (BSD) with a name that corresponds to why the modules belong together
- In the new BSD there's an Edit Button where you add the modules that belong together (A and B in your example)
- Now for the BSD, create a Baseline Set (BS). A BS consists of several baselines, 0 or 1 baselines for each module contained in the BSD. For the BS, define whether the contained Baselines shall have a new major or minor number and define a suffix. The BS will have a number and a suffix, the Baselines will also have the suffix and the next free major/minor number for their respective modules.
- For the new BS, navigate to "Baselines", you will see all modules of the BSD and you will see for which module a Baseline has been created that corresponds to this specific BS
- with "Add to Set" a new Baseline is created for the module(s) you choose
- when Baselines have been created for all modules defined in the BSD (or when you choose not to include a module for a specific BS and press BS --> Close), you will see that the links in the baselines of the BS point to one another.

Comment: PS: you can of course do the same using DXL, see chapters "Baseline Set Definition" and "Baseline Set" in chapter "Modules" of the DXL manual

Comment: Thanks for this and for the detailed explanation, by problems you mean that there will be circular dependencies between the requirements if having bidirectional links?

Comment: Yes, circular dependencies is also one aspect. Also, in a coverage matrix you typically create a table spanning over multiple levels of requirements (e.g. high level, mid level, low level, design, test cases, test results) that is created by iterating over outgoing links. In such a matrix you would check for empty spaces (e.g. "which requirement has not been refined?", "which design object is not related to a requirement?"). When you have bidirectional links, it's not easy to determine these problems. There might be other problems.